# Certified SSL connection is not safe?

Tags: ssl, certificate

I have a site thats not safe.. The Certificate pops up in the address bar when loading, but onload it disappears..

When I comment out this line the connection stays safe when loaded? Why?? The path is relative?!

```
div.welcome {
    margin:0px auto;
    //background:url('/gfx/layout.dialog_body_bg.png') bottom repeat-x #fff8a9;
    border:3px solid #d98704;
    box-shadow:3px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

#httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias secure.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/ini/ssl/secure.domain.com/public.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/ini/ssl/secure.domain.com/private.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /var/ini/ssl/secure.domain.com/intermediate.crt
    SSLVerifyDepth 1
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Perhaps the request for that image redirects to an unsafe page or something odd like that. I think you'll have to debug the specific case. Go to `https://site.tld/gfx/layout.dialog_body_bg.png` and see what happens. Look closely at what you get.

Comment: I can't give you access to the site because its still unofficial

Comment: Seems there's a general problem with the cert. I noted it was only issued yesterday so maybe it wasn't ever working 100%? I just get "Windows does not have enough information to verify the certificate"

Comment: after requesting the image in a seperate window it works.. I also flushed the cache? don't know.. maybe because the cached image was downloaded with `HTTP`? I just added SSL to the server today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the website using the link below, you'll notice that it's currently returning only the server certificate. Scroll to the bottom of the page to see the certificates returned by the server.

http://certlogik.com/sslchecker/secure.dynaccount.com/

Your server should be configured to also return the intermediate cert. This lets the browser build a path from your server cert to one of its trust anchors (Thawte root CA cert). When the intermediate cert is also returned, the SSL Checker website will display a green tick to the left of the word Trusted. Currently there is a warning sign to indicate the missing intermediate certificate.

As an example, this site correctly returns a Thawte intermediate certificate:

http://certlogik.com/sslchecker/nhsprofessionals.nhs.uk

There are lots of CAs that give examples of how to configure webservers to return the cert chain (just use your Thawte certs instead in the examples they give) e.g.,:

[Digicert](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache-cpanel.htm)

[GlobalSign](http://www.globalsign.com/support/install/install_apache.php)

This link from the university of Cambridge provides some good info also:

[Deploying Thawte Certs](http://www.cam.ac.uk/cs/tlscerts/deploying-thawte.html)

Comment: have updated my question.. how do you get the server to return the cert?

Comment: have edited `SSLCACertificateFile` to `SSLCertificateChainFile`, but the site is still not safe?

Comment: You haven't configured it correctly yet as there is still no intermediate cert [SSLChecker](http://certlogik.com/sslchecker/secure.dynaccount.com/)

Comment: +1 for the link to sslchecker. Really nice tool to debug cert issues. Thanks :)

Comment: sorry, but I don't get what I'm missing here.. have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it to work following this guideline from Thawte: https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO14822

The links provided by PhilR are also relevant.

What it seems to come down to is to get apache to serve the entire cert chain.